# A weird box in the code styled with minted

Tags: minted, code

I use `minted` to style my codes in a document. But in some cases, there is a weird box in the code in which most of the time a quotation mark is encircled.

The following MWE shows my problematic issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}
>>> str
<class 'str'>
>>> str.count
<method 'count' of 'str' objects>
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not weird, but the lexer recognizes `class` as a keyword for the declaration of a class (which has a name and not a quoted string), not as terminal output. So you have to create your own lexer (which is not related to minted, but pygmentize) or search for a python console lexer (which seems to exist in pygments.lexers.python.PythonConsoleLexer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygments/pythontex : how to disable red boxes around non usual characters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154849/pygments-pythontex-how-to-disable-red-boxes-around-non-usual-characters)

Comment: For highlighting console output, you want the `pycon` lexer, not `python`.

Comment: @G.Poore OK. How can do it?! I've used `minted` and it does everything! Is there any option for applying it to get a better result?

Comment: @javadr `\begin{minted}{python}` -> `\begin{minted}{pycon}`

Comment: @G.Poore Thanks, it really works. Could you make your comment as a solution?